# Enum for ISO3166 countries - acceptable practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, enums, country-codes

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and it uses a complex model which is serialized/deserialized to/from XML.

Some fields require ISO3166 country codes. I have several defined Enums for other restricted lists (which are very unlikely to change) which are marked with the XmlEnum attribute and displayed neatly using DisplyFor/EditorFor templates.

In order to be consistent I created an Enum of the ISO3166 country codes.

However I am aware these will change overtime requiring me to re-build/deploy the project.

Given the frequency/likelyhood of the ISO3166 codes changing, is this acceptable practice?

Comment: Won't having it in database give you more flexibility ? Your logic should be able to deliver it for the list of codes you can get,Enum you will have to get back to the code always for any change

Comment: @V4Vendetta - Why store them in a DB? Do they change that often?

Comment: @Oded You are right but i have no idea whether its risky or not, how one change can effect the app coz having it as Enum would enforce code having specific conditions based on value rather than a generic one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enumerations are conceptually a related collection of constants, ie. *they do not change*—a client assembly can make this assumption and directly compile in the value of the enum field.

But ISO 3166 does change, [often several times a year](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/updates_on_iso_3166.htm). For example the creation of the new country South Sudan will need to be reflected in an update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; the South Sudan example illustrates why an Enum is not a good option perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this just configuration data? I would XML serialize a `List<MyCountryCodeClass>` of the  country codes and place this in a `CountryCodes.xml` file in the `App_Data` folder.

Comment: I agree with making it a configuration file. I'm not sure if I'd use xml-serialization, but that's only a minor implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had only considered using a DB to store the country codes so alternatives are useful.